# Growl Notification on Folder Modification

Tags: windows-7, growl

I need to create a growl notification on a Windows Fax Server for every time a new fax arrives.  Any suggestions on how to trigger notification to network clients?

OS: Windows 7 x64

Comment: When a fax is received electronically (Windows Fax Server), you want to trigger an alert to let other clients (W7) know that it was received? All on the same network?

Comment: Yes.  I am trying to monitor the network path where it stores it for new faxes/files  (\\fax\inbox) and send alert when new files are available.

Comment: [this may help with some ideas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109786/growl-notifications-from-a-web-server)